# Multiply specific part of a data frame with two conditions r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set that looks like this, called `Data`:

```
Country Region      Code Product name Year Value
Sweden  Stockholm   123  Apple        1991 244   
Sweden  Kirruna     123  Apple        1987 100
Japan   Kyoto       543  Pie          1987 544
Denmark Copenhagen  123  Apple        1998 787
Denmark Copenhagen  123  Apple        1987 100
Denmark Copenhagen  543  Pie          1991 320
Denmark Copenhagen  126  Candy        1999 200
Sweden  Gothenburg  126  Candy        2013 300
Sweden  Gothenburg  157  Tomato       1987 150
Sweden  Stockholm   125  Juice        1987 250
Sweden  Kirruna     187  Banana       1998 310
Japan   Kyoto       198  Ham          1987 157
Japan   Kyoto       125  Juice        1987 550
Japan   Tokyo       125  Juice        1991 100
```

What I want to do is to convert the `value` (sales) to Euro with respect to the specific `country` and `year`. For that I have a data file that I made with the exchange rates for the specific `country` and `year`(that is also adjusted to inflation):

`Exchange_rates <- read_excel("Data/Exchange_rates.xlsx", col_types = c("numeric", "text", "numeric")) #year, country, value`

To get the value I need for `country` and `year` I use this code:

```
Convert_exchage_rate <- function(Specific_Country, Specific_Year) {
    Specific_exchange_rate <- subset(Exchange_rates, Country == Specific_Country)
    Specific_exchange_rate <- subset(Specific_exchange_rate, Year == Specific_Year)
    Specific_exchange_rate <- as.matrix(Specific_exchange_rate[3]) #gets the specific rate for the specific year

    Data <- ??? * Specific_exchange_rate[1] #here comes my question 

}

Convert_exchage_rate("Sweden","1987")
```

My problem is that I do not know how to use R to multiply only the `value` only for the entries in `Data` where `"Country == Sweden"` and `"Year = 1987"` (`Specific_Country` and `Specific_Year` in the function above). I know how to multiply the how value column with `Data$Value <- Data$Value * Specific_exchange_rate[1]`, but now how to it conditionally with two conditions.

(later on I will make a loop to run my function for all years and all countries in `Data`, but I did not want to write that part of the code until I can get this to work for one specific country at one specific year)

Comment: I guess you just need to subset the relevant rows. `Data$Value[Data$Country == "Sweden" & Data$Year == 1987]`. Replace `Data$Value[Data$Country == Specific_Country & Data$Year == Specific_Year]` instead of `???` in your function ?

Comment: i think you can left join country and year from excel file to main file and after that just multiply the sales with exchange rate

Comment: Ah, thanks, now I know how to make two conditions. That will be very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the commented line of your function, you could do

```
Data$Value[Data$Country == Specific_Country & Data$Year == Specific_Year] <-
Data$Value[Data$Country == Specific_Country & Data$Year == Specific_Year] * Specific_exchange_rate[1]
```

This should be pretty self explanatory: you choose the specific Data$Value's which match your Specific_Country and Specific_Year.

You can avoid the loop by doing the following

```
Data <- merge(Data, Exchange_rates, by=c('Country','Year'))
Data$Value_in_eur <- Data$Specific_exchange_rate * Data$Value
```

Comment: That one seems to work, thanks a lot! Just one question: My data file with exchange rates contains more years (2000-2017) than for some countries in that sales data. For Denmark in the real data for instance, I only have sales data for 2010-2017, but I have exchange rates for 2000-2017. Does that matter when I use `merge`?

Comment: By default, merge uses an inner join. I.e. the resulting data frame only has the observations for the rows where the country and year columns match between the two datasets.  For details, see `?merge`, in particular the switches all.x and all.y.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it up - your solution was perfect.